# Want to upload a bunch of files one after another at a specific time

Tags: android, android-service, android-networking

I want to upload files from a specified directory at a specific time everyday (let say 7:00 PM)whether the application active or not.
there are many option but i am confuse, that which one is the best for this situation.

1. should i use an Alarm Manager to start the broadcast receiver and
   then inside it ,will start a service where the file upload will take
   place.
2. should i use an Alarm Manager to start a service where the file upload will takeplace.
3. or use any other option like JobSchedulerand etc.

will service will work because of background restriction ?

Comment: use [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/) support library

Comment: What have you already tried and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

The best suggestion is to use `WorkManager`, with `WorkManager` you can manage your file uploading queue also you can manage time, also some other properties like the device are in charging state or not.

Official Link : [`WorkManager`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics)
Basic Tutorial : [Tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager/#0)